# Retrieve Child Items by Folder Id Using Google Drive API

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

Is there any efficient way of loading items by parent folder id? Till now I've only found these ways:

```
var children = _driveService.Children.List(folderId).Execute().Items;

var result = children.Select(i =>
{
     var item = _driveService.Files.Get(i.Id).Execute();

     return item;
});
```

and

```
var items = _driveService.Files.List();

items.Q = string.Format("'{0}' in parents", folderId);

var result = items.Execute().Items;
```

But I don't like them, because they are slow and also look stupid. Isn't there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the 2 way the best, because it's simpler to add other conditions (ex. trashed=false to get only file not trashed) so you can get a single function for search and list All.

Using the Google Drive API a lot, I've found out that the main problem with performance is due to the huge amount of information attached to a single file (last time , while most of the time we need only a couple of those for our application; luckily you can get partial responses using the `items` parameter in the search (more information available in the [Performance Tips documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/performance)).

As a rule of thumb, after some tests I made last year, getting only title, last update date and id transfer nearly 90% less data for each result, quite the improvement in data transfer.

If you **really** need to get all the file metadata, I advise you to first get the list of items as in Example 2 but only the `fileId`, than use Parallel.ForEach (.Net 4.0+) to get all the files metadata with parallel requests.

Comment: Agree with the first part, but not necessarily the use of multiple parallel file.gets. That could generate a lot of http requests which count against quota. You could end up being flow-controlled by Drive, which is not a happy place to be. I've found paging through list results, with the items parameter set appropriately and gzip enabled gives the best throughput. You can alway start with a small maxResults so your user isn't waiting too long for the first results, and then increase it to 100 for subsequent requests.

Comment: @smokybob, thanks, I forgot to check the performance tips sections. Now I tried this: 

items.Fields = "items(id,title,fileSize,mimeType)";

It worked, but it's still damn slow. So, you're saying that I should use TPL and there's no 'elegant' way of optimizing it?

Comment: @GiorgiZautashvili TPL is needed only when you need "big" data for a lot of files; because as pointed out by pinoyyid, you'll hit the max request quota faster (it's 10 million Reqs/day; if you have 1.000 users it's possible). We only have a case where using TPL is reasonable to get metadata, and is to Clone files to another account; otherwise we get the limited files to display the information as fast as possible (normally 1/2 sec top) and load the details of the file only when the user select it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to improve performance by doing it this way:

```
var items = _driveService.Files.List();

items.Q = string.Format("'{0}' in parents and trashed = false", folderId);
items.Fields = "items(id,title,fileSize,mimeType)";

var result = items.Execute().Items;
```

Thanks to @smokybob